# How to get text from combobox in php in different page?

Tags: php, combobox

this is my code in the first page

```
<?php
session_start();
$fullname = $_SESSION['fullname'];
$success_page = './chart.php';
if(isset($_POST['Button1'])) {

    $_SESSION['month'] = $_POST['Combobox1'];
    $_SESSION['year'] = $_POST['Combobox2'];
    header('Location: '.$success_page);
}
```

?>

And this is my 2nd page

```
session_start();
$fullname = $_SESSION['fullname'];
$month = $_SESSION['month'];
$year = $_SESSION['year'];
echo $month;
echo $year;
echo $fullname;
```

There are 2 combobox in my 1st page and or some reason I'm not able to echo the month and year in my 2nd page. Thanks for the help!

EDIT: this is the html part with my form

```
<select name="Combobox1" size="1" id="Combobox1" style="position:absolute;left:550px;top:580px;width:250px;height:50px;z-    index:1;">
<option value="1">Janvier</option>
<option value="2">Février</option>
<option value="3">Mars</option>
<option value="4">Avril</option>
<option value="5">Mai</option>
<option value="6">Juin</option>
<option value="7">Juillet</option>
<option value="8">Août</option>
<option value="9">Septembre</option>
<option value="10">Octobre</option>
<option value="11">Novembre</option>
<option value="12">Décembre</option>
</select>
<select name="Combobox2" size="1" id="Combobox2" style="position:absolute;left:900px;top:580px;width:250px;height:50px;z-index:1;">
<option>2014</option>
<option>2015</option>

<form method='post' action='mois.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type="submit" id="Button1" name="Button1" value="Submit" style="position:absolute;left:800px;top:700px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:2;">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML markup as well?

Comment: Can you please show the complete HTML code which includes the `form` tag.

Comment: Your `select` tags should be inside the `form` tag. Than and than only there values will be passed to the PHP page you have given in the `action` attribute.